# Create global list object Java

Tags: java

I want to create a global list of object accessible to all the class of my package.

For example, here the class that create the object

```
public class Class2 {

protected String one, two, three;

public void newItem(String one, String two, String three) {

    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
    this.three = three;
}

public String getInfo() {

    return one + "," + two + "," + three;
}
```

I want to create a list of object Class2 from another class (suppose Class1.java) and I want that list to be available from another class, lets say Class3.java.

The behaviour should be like a database, where one class create the List and other class read that list to perform some local actions.

Comment: How about showing us your best effort first? Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how about dependency injection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution without any additional dependencies and singletons:

```
//Class which represents this "data storage" of yours. You can even have multiple instances of it simultaneously if you need
class Database {
    //Some data the DB contains
    private List<MyEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    //Way to read the stored data
    public List<MyEntity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    //Way to add new data
    public void addEntity(MyEntity newEntity) {
        entities.add(newEntity);
    }
}

//Some working class, which fills the database with information
class EntityCreator {
    private final Database db;

    //Each working class attaches itself to specific database instance. Therefore, you need to pass that instance through the constructor and save it for later job
    public EntityCreator(Database operationalDb) {
        this.db = operationalDb;
    }

    public void writeSomeData() {
        for (.....) {
            db.addEntity(new MyEntity(...));
        }
    }
}

//Some working class, which depends on information saved in database
class EntityReader {
    private final Database db;

    //Each working class attaches itself to specific database instance. Therefore, you need to pass that instance through the constructor and save it for later job
    public EntityCreator(Database operationalDb) {
        this.db = operationalDb;
    }

    public void doSomeWork() {
        for (MyEntity e : db.getEntities()) {
            doStuff(e);
        }
    }
}

//Example of the full workflow
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database db = new Database();
        EntityCreator creator = new EntityCreator(db);
        EntityReader reader = new EntityReader(db);

        creator.writeSomeData();
        reader.doSomeWork();
    }
}
```

Also, it is worth noticing, it is not thread safe, but it gives the main idea behind wiring dependencies together without using DI frameworks.

Comment: after i implements this on my program an Exception occurred. i think you right to say is not thread safe, i think i have to study another solution to elaborate data of the db inside the Java Fx Application Thread.

Comment: The easy way (probably not very optimized to your specific scenario) is to wrap ArrayList with `Collections.synchronizedList`. That is, in the `Database` class, change the list declaration to `private List<MyEntity> entities = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MyEntity>())`. That should make it somewhat thread safe. Also, again, this is a fast and dirty solution, as the proper thread-safety solution depends on the specific scenarios you use your "database".

Comment: thanks a lot but i got Exception the same. i think the problem is the task i use to read the DB. I saw this page http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html and i think i have to implement something like that.